# MongoDB transaction doesn't work as expected - Incorrect total price on “order” document when its "order items" are being updated concurrently

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions

I have 2 collections: *order* and *orderitems* where an order consists of order item(s).

The order has field *price* which should be the sum of the price of the order items only if the *status* is “new”.

For example, order ABC has 3 order items :

1. Price: 5, status: “new”
2. Price: 10, status: “paid”
3. Price: 15, status: “new”

This order should have the price = **20**.

What happens is sometimes the order price does not calculate correctly when the order items’ status is updated **concurrently** from “new” to “paid” or vice versa.

For example, when order item 1 and 3 are updated to “paid”, the order price is still 20 instead of 0.

My update order item API (Node JS) looks like this:

```
    const orderitem = await services
      .query("orderitem")
      .findOne({ _id: orderitemId });
    const currStatus = orderitem.status;
    const newStatus = request.status ?? currStatus;
    const currPrice = orderitem.price;
    const newPrice = request.price ?? currPrice;
    const statusNew = "new";
    let inc = 0.0;

    if (newStatus === statusNew && currStatus === statusNew) {
      inc = newPrice - currPrice;
    } else if (newStatus === statusNew && currStatus !== statusNew) {
      inc = newPrice;
    } else if (newStatus !== statusNew && currStatus === statusNew) {
      inc = currPrice * -1;
    }

    const session = services.common.startDbSession();

    try {
      await session.withTransaction(async () => {
        if (inc !== 0.0) {
          await services.order.updateOutstandingBalance(
            orderitem.order._id,
            inc,
            session
          );
        }

        await services
          .query("orderitem")
          .model.updateOne(params, request)
          .session(session);
      });
    } finally {
      await session.endSession();
    }
```

And here is the *updateOutstandingBalance* function:

```
    updateOutstandingBalance: async (_id, inc = 0.0, session = null) => {
      await services
        .query("order")
        .model.updateOne(
          { _id: _id },
          {
            $inc: { price: inc },
            updatedAt: new Date(),
            myLock: { appName: "myApp", pseudoRandom: new ObjectID() },
          }
        )
        .session(session);
    }
```

It seems like the update sometimes just doesn’t `$inc` correctly.

p.s: The transaction is using *write concern* "majority" and *read concern* “local”.

What I have tried so far:

1. Calculate the total of the order item price using `$sum` (the read is also inside the transaction) then update the order
2. Write-lock all the order's orderitems but this caused a lot of spikes on the database operations because of the write retry
3. Use write concern "majority" and read concern "majority" or “snapshot”

And, this issue still happens.

Any help is really appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens is sometimes the order price does not calculate correctly when the order items’ status is updated concurrently from “new” to “paid” or vice versa.
>
> For example, when order item 1 and 3 are updated to “paid”, the order price is still 20 instead of 0.

So, you have process A which changes item status and process B which calculates order price.

These operations are linearizable with  B executing first and A executing second.

Trigger price update (another one) after status change.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.

Initially, the sequence of the operations was A then B, and was having the same issue.
Then I swapped it hoping that B triggers immediately to "lock" the order document during the transaction so other concurrent requests will "wait".
And technically, B does not have to rely on the order data because it only "increment" based on the order item's price and status.